# Network priority is not being observed—how to fix?

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I have my home network listed as highest priority in my list of Wifi networks, and my Karma Go (like a Mifi) listed ***way*** down the list, and yet I very frequently discover that I'm using my Karma Go when I'm at home and my home network is available and working just fine.  How can I get my Mac to work properly and always choose the higher-priority network over the lower-priority network?

Comment: Why do you have two connections to the Internet live in the first place?

Comment: That should be pretty obvious: I was using the Karma Go and came home.  My computer should switch to the higher-priority network as soon as its available.  But there are lots of scenarios that would result in two networks live at once, which is why Apple lets you prioritize them.

Comment: In short, the network priority you see there is "all things being equal" your priority will be whatever you have configured.  **However**, while you may be in range of your home WiFi, your MiFI in your bag may have a vastly better connection and thusly, it will direct traffic there.  Additionally, it won't do a handoff; meaning if it's connected, even far down the list, it will stay connected until you disconnect then when you do reconnect, it will reconnect to higher priority first.